# SQL - Getting a value from one of multiple sources based on condition

Tags: sql

I have the following table structure:

TransactionTable

```
transactID  TBarcode   Ecode  PAICID  status
1            1234      E001    1         0
2            4567      E002    2         1
```

UserMasterTable

```
Uid   Uname Ecode
1      jas   E001
2      biju   E002
```

EmployeeMasterTable

```
Ecode        Ename
E001         Jaseem
E002         bijeesh
```

`TransactionTable.PAICD` and `UserMasterTable.Uid` are the same.

I'm searching on `TBarcde` (I mean a condition like `WHERE Tbarcode = 1234`)

If `status` is 0 then then i want the corresponding `Ename` related to the `TransactionTable.Ecode`.

If `status` is 1 then i want to take the `Ename` from the corresponding `PAICID` Ename of `UserMasterTable.Ecode`.

How I can write a Stored Procedure for this?

Comment: i am new in stored procedure,,,so am thinking how to write this??

Comment: What do you mean by "take" and "show"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a stored procedure for this.  The following query will do what you need:

It's left-joining `TransactionTable` on `EmployeeMasterTable` directly and through `UserMasterTable`, then selecting the Ename from the proper joined employee table based on the status criterion

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN t.status = 0 
            THEN e0.Ename 
        ELSE e1.Ename 
    END AS Ename
FROM TransactionTable AS t
LEFT JOIN EmployeeMasterTable AS e0
    ON t.Ecode = e1.Ecode
LEFT JOIN UserMasterTable AS u
    ON t.PAICID = u.Uid
LEFT JOIN EmployeeMasterTable AS e1
    ON u.Ecode = e1.Ecode
WHERE TBarcode = 1234
```

If you do need it in a stored procedure, reference the docs for your DBMS on how to do so.  It'l probably be something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure (IN iTBarcode INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        CASE 
            WHEN t.status = 0 
                THEN e0.Ename 
            ELSE e1.Ename 
        END AS Ename
    FROM TransactionTable AS t
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeMasterTable AS e0
        ON t.Ecode = e1.Ecode
    LEFT JOIN UserMasterTable AS u
        ON t.PAICID = u.Uid
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeMasterTable AS e1
        ON u.Ecode = e1.Ecode
    WHERE TBarcode = iTBarcode
END
```

Comment: I will check and let u know,,,

Comment: Edited to add TBarcode condition and flesh out the stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` to UsermasterTable, putting the status in the join condition, you can then INNER JOIN EmployeeMasterTable using COALESCE, so stating when there is a match in UserMasterTable use the ECode from that, otherwise use the Ecode from the TransactionTable

```
SELECT  TransactionTable.TransactID,
        TransactionTable.TBarCode,
        TransactionTable.ECode,
        TransactionTable.PAICID,
        TransactionTable.Status,
        EmployeeMasterTable.Ename
FROM    TransactionTable
        LEFT JOIN UserMasterTable
            ON UserMasterTable.ECode = TransactionTable.ECode
            AND TransactionTable.Status = 0
        INNER JOIN EmployeeMasterTable
            ON EmployeeMasterTable.ECode = COALESCE(UserMasterTable.ECode, TransactionTable.ECode)
WHERE   TransactionTable.BarCode = '1234';
```

Comment: while executing your first procedure showing error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: I've removed that now, I misread your criteria and found a solution that doesn't require a case statement

Comment: Good creative solution.  +1